# touch in Browserstack

Tags: selenium, webdriver, browserstack

I try to use the touch feature (for testing a website with touch function in a mobile browser) in Browserstack but any code I "try and error" leads to an exception. Does anyone know an examplary code in an arbitrary programming language for an arbitrary mobile device?

Comment: Doesn't work with click? if you don't have a swipe then click should be ok.

Comment: in this case unfortunately the developpers needed to deactivate the click

Comment: In this case maybe you could use a javascript script, ask dev team for some help in creating this script.